# VBA to concatenate and then increment resulting value based on another value

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I am trying to write a macro to loop through a spreadsheet, and on each row, concatenate three values (from different columns) into a single value (integer), and result that in another column on the same row.  Then, increment from that number, based on the number from a different value in the column.  Each iteration of this (including the first one) should copy the first column's value from that row, so that each increment reflects the same information in the newly created output.

Here's an example of the input data:

[image]

B2, C2, and D2 should all be concatenated, resulting in the number 5555551000, and that should be placed in cell I2.  A2 should be copied to H2, as I2's location identifier.  I2 should then be incremented based on the value of F2 (in this case, 10 times), and those results should be iterated under I2 starting at I3, with A2's value to the left of each output's cell, in the corresponding H column.

Here's an example of the output on the same sheet:

[image]

Once the output completes for expanding the first range of numbers, the loop continues to the next row and repeats the process.

I took a stab at this by setting the starting point, then doing a for loop with row.Count and inside of this, doing a Do While loop and breaking the loop based on the DID integer.  I'm not having much success and perhaps it has to do with the way I'm using ActiveCell to try to move around during the iterations.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I'm not allowed to embed pictures yet, thus the external links to the examples.

Comment: Please post your code so that we can help you with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have pointed out, its a lot easier to understand and troubleshoot what you're trying to do when you post the code, but I took a stab at it and came up with the following- quick note, this sub takes place on 2 different sheets (the source sheet, and then the resulting output sheet). If you really need it on the same sheet then I guess you could output the data right on top of the old data.

```
Public Sub sampleSub()
Dim sourceWS As Worksheet
Dim sourceData() As Variable
Dim outputRange As Range
Dim outputArr() As Variable
Dim readCounter As Long
Dim writeCounter As Long
Dim iterationCounter As Long

Set sourceWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
sourceData = sourceWS.Range("A2:F4").Value2 'Read in source data

'Redim outout array with enough rows to be able to store each iteration (column F => 10 + 120 + 1000...)
ReDim outputArr(1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(sourceWS.Range("F2:F4")), 1 To 9)

For readCounter = 1 To UBound(sourceData, 1)    'Loop through each row of source data
    For iterationCounter = 0 To sourceData(readCounter, 6) - 1  'Iterates to # in source data column F
        writeCounter = writeCounter + 1
        outputArr(writeCounter, 1) = sourceData(readCounter, 1) 'Write source data column A to output column A
        outputArr(writeCounter, 2) = sourceData(readCounter, 2) 'Write source data column B to output column B
        outputArr(writeCounter, 3) = sourceData(readCounter, 3) 'Write source data column C to output column C
        outputArr(writeCounter, 4) = sourceData(readCounter, 4) 'Write source data column D to output column D
        outputArr(writeCounter, 5) = sourceData(readCounter, 5) 'Write source data column E to output column E
        outputArr(writeCounter, 6) = sourceData(readCounter, 6) 'Write source data column F to output column F
        outputArr(writeCounter, 7) = sourceData(readCounter, 7) 'Write source data column G to output column G
        outputArr(writeCounter, 8) = sourceData(readCounter, 1) 'Write source data column A to output column H
        'Concatonate source data columns B, C & D and then adds iteration counter
        outputArr(writeCounter, 9) = CLng(sourceData(readCounter, 2) & sourceData(readCounter, 3) & sourceData(readCounter, 4)) + iterationCounter
    Next
Next

'User selects target range and then data is outputted
Set outputRange = Application.InputBox("Select target for output:", Type:=8)
outputRange.Resize(UBound(outputArr, 1), UBound(outputArr, 2)) = outputArr

End Sub
```

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode

Comment: TheSilkCode, this looks good, I hadn't thought of doing it like this.  I will re-write mine based on what you have here and report back.  Thanks so much for the quick response!